# How to Check or Test JMS Url is Active Before Sending Message in WSO2 ESB

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any way or any configurations in WSO2 ESB to test JMS endpoint before sending actual message. I have searched alot but didn't find any solution. I need help from WSO2 experts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is no option in WSO2, just send a test message and check.